# Manipulating a dataframe conditionally

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data I am attempt to do the following;

1. If elements in tag_3 & tag_4 are 'NaN' then return an intermediate df with the   following columns: tag_0, tag_1 & tag_2.
2. If elements in tag_4 only are 'NaN' then return another intermediate df with the following columns: tag_0, tag_2, tag_3.
3. Finally if ALL columns have non-NaN values then return an intermediate df with the following columns: tag_0, tag_3, tag_4.

DATA:

```
data = {'tag_0': ['1', '2', '3'],
        'tag_1': ['4', '5', '6'],
        'tag_2': ['7', '8', '9'],
        'tag_3': ['NaN', '10', '11'],
        'tag_4': ['NaN', 'NaN', '12']}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['tag_0', 'tag_1', 'tag_2', 'tag_3', 'tag_4'])
```

[dummy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So6az.png)

Answer (score 1):

I like to use bool masks for this sort of task in pandas because I think it is easy to read, but there are other ways to go about it.

**What is bool mask?**

A bool mask is essentially a `Series` of True/False values that is applied to a `DataFrame` to filter it.

---

*Step 1: create the `Series` of True/False values.*

```
tag_3_is_nan = df['tag3'].isna()
tag_4_is_nan = df['tag4'].isna()
```

*Step 2: apply them to the `DataFrame`*

```
df[bool_mask]
```

In your case this would be applied using the following logic.

***Case 1: If elements in tag_3 & tag_4 are 'NaN' then return an intermediate df with the following columns: tag_0, tag_1 & tag_2.***

```
df[tag_3_is_nan & tag_4_is_nan][['tag_0', 'tag_1', 'tag_2']]
```

***Case 2: If elements in tag_4 only are 'NaN' then return another intermediate df with the following columns: tag_0, tag_2, tag_3.***

```
df[tag_4_is_nan & ~tag_3_is_nan][['tag_0', 'tag_2', 'tag_3']]
```

The `~` is equal to `not` - so `~tag_3_is_nan` means tag_3 is not nan.

***Case 3: Finally if ALL columns have non-NaN values then return an intermediate df with the following columns: tag_0, tag_3, tag_4.***

Dropping all rows that contain at least one NaN value is simple in pandas - just use the method `dropna()`

```
df.dropna()[['tag_0', 'tag_3', 'tag_4']]
```

- To avoid `settingWithCopyWarning` down the line you should copy the filtered `df`.

---

Above uses `None` but your example uses `'NaN'` as a `string`. You can use the same method if your data contains strings of `'NaN'` rather than actual `None`.

```
tag_3_is_nan_string = df['tag3'] == 'NaN'
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try your solution & let you know how it turns out! This looks pretty cool!!

Comment: Glad you liked it! Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Worked with some minor modifications!! Shout out to you @ user3471881 for this cool solution!!